# How to send list as JSON response in python API?

Tags: python, json, list, api, response

I'm listing gke-firewall in python. I need to send a list of firewalls as response to Python API.So that it can be used by another API.

**My Python API execution:**

```
Calling API_1
  |
  |___  ...Executing API_1...
        Calling API_2
            |
            |___ ...Executing API_2...
                  <list the firewalls and returning the list in JSON DataFormat as API response.>
                 ...Returning response to API_1...
         ...Executing API_1...<By using firewall list>
         ...Executed Successfully...
```

I'm able to list the data but I don't know how to send it as a JSON response. Is it possible Or is there is any other way to achieve this..?

```
**Executing API_2**
def firewall():
  list_firewall = []
  status = "True"
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect(hostname = HOSTNAME,username = USERNAME,key_filename = FILENAME)
  cmd = 'gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project <project-name> --filter="name~gke-<your-cluster-name>-[0-9a-z]*"'
  stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
  for line in (stdout.read().splitlines()):
      data = line.split()[0]
      list_firewall.append(data)
  print(list_firewall)
  ssh.close()
  #return .. <Return list_firewall and status as json data>
```

How to return the list as JSON data as an API response?. Is there any method to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON `dumps` to dump the contents of that list you've created as a JSON string:

```py
import json
**Executing API_2**
def firewall():
  list_firewall = []
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect(hostname = HOSTNAME,username = USERNAME,key_filename = FILENAME)
  cmd = 'gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project <project-name> --filter="name~gke-<your-cluster-name>-[0-9a-z]*"'
  stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
  for line in (stdout.read().splitlines()):
      data = line.split()[0]
      list_firewall.append(data)
  ssh.close()
  return json.dumps(list_firewall)
```

If you need a json *object*  because the API framework handles the conversion to string, then just return the list itself.